# C++ boost asio example code compile error on VS2013 express

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, boost-asio

I am trying to run the asio 1.57 tcp server example code on VS2013 express version. I am getting following errors:

```
9   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0" is undefined d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\multicast.hpp 51  3   tcpserver
16  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0" is undefined d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\unicast.hpp   59  3   tcpserver
3   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x00000001" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\resolver_query_base.hpp   67  15  tcpserver
2   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x00000002" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\resolver_query_base.hpp   66  22  tcpserver
4   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x00000004" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\resolver_query_base.hpp   68  20  tcpserver
5   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x00000008" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\resolver_query_base.hpp   69  23  tcpserver
7   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x00000100" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\resolver_query_base.hpp   71  20  tcpserver
8   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x00000400" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\resolver_query_base.hpp   72  26  tcpserver
6   IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x00000800" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\resolver_query_base.hpp   70  17  tcpserver
15  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_0x0001" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\tcp.hpp   126 37  tcpserver
13  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_10" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\multicast.hpp 144 3   tcpserver
14  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_11" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\multicast.hpp 181 3   tcpserver
10  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_12" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\multicast.hpp 52  3   tcpserver
11  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_13" is undefined    d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\multicast.hpp 80  3   tcpserver
17  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_4" is undefined d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\unicast.hpp   60  3   tcpserver
12  IntelliSense: identifier "BOOST_ASIO_OS_DEF_9" is undefined d:\project\lib\boost_1_57_0\boost\asio\ip\multicast.hpp 108 3   tcpserver
```

Comment: This is IntelliSense errors, not compiler. Does project compile successfully?

Comment: Yes, the project compiles fine, just wondering how to fix the Intellisense errors. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are `IntelliSense` errors, you can suppress them by right clicking on the list and unticking "Show IntelliSense Errors".